# Errors while compiling Thrift c++ libraries

Tags: c++, sockets, thrift

I am writing client samples for Airavata C++ API, which includes the thrift c++ libraries. I am getting a whole lot of errors while compiling, due to the included thrift libraries. I am using the following command for compilation:

gcc -I/home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/ -Wall -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H $(INC)  `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` createProject.cpp `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`

I managed to figure out the problem for some, but am currently stuck at the following errors. Any suggestions on how to fix these will be helpful.

```
/home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:187:25: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo’
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.h:245:30: error: forward declaration of ‘struct apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo’
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:187:41: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo’
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.h:245:30: error: forward declaration of ‘struct apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo’
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:187:59: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo’
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.h:245:30: error: forward declaration of ‘struct apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo’
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:243:24: error: aggregate ‘apache::thrift::transport::TSocket::openConnection(apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo*)::sockaddr_un address’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:263:31: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo’
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.h:245:30: error: forward declaration of ‘struct apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo’
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:263:62: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo’
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.h:245:30: error: forward declaration of ‘struct apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo’
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:278:29: error: elements of array ‘apache::thrift::transport::TSocket::openConnection(apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo*)::pollfd fds [1]’ have incomplete type
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:278:29: error: storage size of ‘fds’ isn’t known
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:281:19: error: ‘POLLOUT’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:282:41: error: ‘poll’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:318:25: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo’
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.h:245:30: error: forward declaration of ‘struct apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo’
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:318:62: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo’
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.h:245:30: error: forward declaration of ‘struct apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo’
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp: In member function ‘void apache::thrift::transport::TSocket::local_open()’:
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:355:19: error: aggregate ‘apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo hints’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:363:20: error: ‘AI_PASSIVE’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:363:33: error: ‘AI_ADDRCONFIG’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:366:57: error: ‘getaddrinfo’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:369:106: error: ‘gai_strerror’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:377:34: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo’
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.h:245:30: error: forward declaration of ‘struct apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo’
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:382:14: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo’
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.h:245:30: error: forward declaration of ‘struct apache::thrift::transport::addrinfo’
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:386:26: error: ‘freeaddrinfo’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:393:20: error: ‘freeaddrinfo’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp: In member function ‘virtual uint32_t apache::thrift::transport::TSocket::read(uint8_t*, uint32_t)’:
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:434:37: error: ‘gettimeofday’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:454:37: error: ‘gettimeofday’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp: In member function ‘std::string apache::thrift::transport::TSocket::getPeerHost()’:
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:717:21: error: ‘NI_MAXHOST’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:718:24: error: ‘NI_MAXSERV’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:721:17: error: ‘clienthost’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:722:17: error: ‘clientservice’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:722:56: error: ‘getnameinfo’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp: In member function ‘std::string apache::thrift::transport::TSocket::getPeerAddress()’:
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:751:21: error: ‘NI_MAXHOST’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:752:24: error: ‘NI_MAXSERV’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:755:17: error: ‘clienthost’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:756:17: error: ‘clientservice’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:757:17: error: ‘NI_NUMERICHOST’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:757:32: error: ‘NI_NUMERICSERV’ was not declared in this scope
    /home/ixxi-2013/Desktop/airavata-cpp-sdk/lib/thrift/transport/TSocket.cpp:757:46: error: ‘getnameinfo’ was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you [have found out in the meantime](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/thrift-user/201407.mbox/ajax/%3CCACZTvVuO%2BM5YHjvGMYT7civnUFe1WD51MKY5M-R3GAD-hJci-A%40mail.gmail.com%3E) ;-), just follow the [steps outlined in the documentation](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/BuildingFromSource):

```
cd thrift
./bootstrap.sh
./configure
make
make install
```